# Sub query in join with 3rd table

Tags: mysql, sql

My Current Join Query

```
select c.email
       , c.name
       , o.created
       , o.customerId
       , o.code as order_code
       , o.totalValue
       ,'cash' as description
       , o.WalletCash as amount 
from   Order o join Customer c  on o.customerId = c.id 
where  o.WalletCash > 0 
and    o.created BETWEEN '2022-03-16' AND '2022-03-16'
```

I want to make join or sub query with below query

```
select customerId from   CustomerWallet where  customerId =100
```

The `Customer`, `CustomerWallet`and `Order` tables are all associated by CustomerID.

**How join 3rd table in join query in mysql?**

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to restrict the first query result to customer IDs found with the second query?

Answer (score 0):

You can alias the first query and use that with the second table.

```
select * from (select c.email
       , c.name
       , o.created
       , o.customerId
       , o.code as order_code
       , o.totalValue
       ,'cash' as description
       , o.WalletCash as amount 
from   Order o join Customer c  on o.customerId = c.id 
where  o.WalletCash > 0 
and    o.created BETWEEN '2022-03-16' AND '2022-03-16') tab t join CustomerWallet c on t.order_code = c.order_code and c.order_code = like "%abc%"
```

or you can join all three tables together.

```
select c.email
       , c.name
       , o.created
       , o.customerId
       , o.code as order_code
       , o.totalValue
       ,'cash' as description
       , o.WalletCash as amount 
from   Order o join Customer c  on o.customerId = c.id 
       join CustomerWallet w on w.order_code = order_code
where  o.WalletCash > 0 
and    o.created BETWEEN '2022-03-16' AND '2022-03-16' 
and w.order_code like "%abc%"
```

Comment: `order_code` not available in `CustomerWallet` table.`OrderCode` is different from `Order` table

Comment: I took it from question. You can use whatever corresponding column you have in CustomerWallet.

Comment: getting this error `Unknown column 'o.WalletCash' in 'field list'`

Comment: Again this is from question only , o.WalletCash as amount

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the first query's result to customer IDs found in the second query, then use `IN`:

```
select c.email
       , c.name
       , o.created
       , o.customerId
       , o.code as order_code
       , o.totalValue
       ,'cash' as description
       , o.WalletCash as amount 
from   Order o join Customer c  on o.customerId = c.id 
where  o.WalletCash > 0 
and    o.created BETWEEN '2022-03-16' AND '2022-03-16' 
and    c.id in
       (
         select customerId 
         from   CustomerWallet 
         where  order_code like '%abc%'
       );
```

I see that there is an `order_code` in `CustomerWallet`. There is a `code` in your `order` table, too. Maybe you want to consider this in your lokup. Probably:

```
and    (o.code, c.id) in
       (
         select cw.order_code, cw.customerId 
         from   CustomerWallet cw
         where  cw.order_code like '%abc%'
       );
```

`IN` and `EXISTS` are appropriate for such lookups. As opposed to a join they just ensure a match exists. With joins you could involuntarily produce duplicate rows in case the second itself returns the join criteria multifold.

Comment: order_code not available in `CustomerWallet` table. OrderCode is diffrent from order table

Comment: That was just guessing, because you used the same name order_code as an alias name. So, is my first query what you are after? Or what else do you want to achieve? You'l have to explain how you want the queries to be related.